# Cant add Contex Value with Chi from interface

Tags: go, go-chi

i have data from interface, and i will add on context. from documentation is `context.WithValue(r.Context(), key, val)`

i try to add 1 key and value is work, but can't work if more than 1.

```
        result := map[string]interface{}{}
        encoded, _ := json.Marshal(data)
        json.Unmarshal(encoded, &result)
        fmt.Println("data claim \n", result)
        var ctx context.Context
        for key, val := range result {
            fmt.Printf("key %v value %v \n", key, val)
            ctx = context.WithValue(r.Context(), key, val)
        }
        fmt.Println("ctx middleware \n", ctx)
```

on result i have more than 1 data, but only 1 data is work.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try this

```
        result := map[string]interface{}{}
        encoded, _ := json.Marshal(data)
        json.Unmarshal(encoded, &result)
        fmt.Println("data claim \n", result)
        ctx:=r.Context()
        for key, val := range result {
            fmt.Printf("key %v value %v \n", key, val)
            ctx = context.WithValue(ctx, key, val)
        }
        fmt.Println("ctx middleware \n", ctx)
```

Seems you are using `r.Context()` all the time but not the updated one.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using the type `string` for the context key. This problem is already mentioned in the [context document](https://pkg.go.dev/context#WithValue).

> The provided key must be comparable and should not be of type string or any other built-in type to avoid collisions between packages using context

Here is the example for getting and setting key/value in context

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "log"
)

// You need to define a type to prevent the collision
type key int

const fooKey key = 1
const barKey key = 2

func main() {

    ctx := context.Background()
    m := map[key]string{
        fooKey: "foo",
        barKey: "bar",
    }

    // Add to context
    for k, v := range m {
        ctx = context.WithValue(ctx, k, v)
    }

    // Get value from context
    for k := range m {
        v := ctx.Value(k).(string)
        log.Println("value is: ", v)
    }
}
```